# Difference fork() and sys_fork()

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I seen all system calls (say x) are related with a another call as sys_x():
Ex: fork and sys_fork(),open() and sys_open() etc.

What is significance of these sys_x() calls? Where we can use these calls?

Answer (score 4):

> What is significance of these sys_x() calls?

As the name indicates, these are the actual syscalls being executed in kernel mode.

You see, when you call `fork(2)` or `open(2)` from your application, you are not invoking a raw syscall directly; instead, you're invoking glibc's wrappers that know how to call the actual syscall. This indirection step is needed because syscall invocation is architecture specific, so the details are hidden in glibc.

> Where we can use these calls?

You don't. For one, `sys_fork()` is Linux-specific; other UNIX variants are not required to (and probably they don't) implement a `sys_fork()` function. The exact functions inside the kernel that deal with forking are system dependent. It just so happens that Linux has a function called `sys_fork()`, `sys_open()`, etc.

For example, in the case of `fork(2)`, in Linux the flow is more or less like:

`fork()` -> glibc wrapper -> raw syscall invocation -> transition to kernel mode -> syscall lookup -> `sys_fork()` -> `do_fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example where `sys_fork()` would come in useful.

The Mono .net runtime tries to run a debugger as part of its crash handler. The signal handlers on Unix can only run async-safe functions, otherwise deadlocks can happen. So, Mono avoids using `fork()` and instead issues the syscall more directly:

```c
#if !defined (HOST_WIN32)
/**
 * fork_crash_safe:
 *
 * Version of \c fork that is safe to call from an async context such as a
 * signal handler even if the process crashed inside libc.
 *
 * Returns 0 to the child process, >0 to the parent process or <0 on error.
 */
static pid_t
fork_crash_safe (void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    /*
     * glibc fork acquires some locks, so if the crash happened inside malloc/free,
     * it will deadlock. Call the syscall directly instead.
     */
#if defined(HOST_ANDROID)
    /* SYS_fork is defined to be __NR_fork which is not defined in some ndk versions */
    g_assert_not_reached ();
#elif !defined(HOST_DARWIN) && defined(SYS_fork)
    pid = (pid_t) syscall (SYS_fork);
#elif HAVE_FORK
    pid = (pid_t) fork ();
#else
    g_assert_not_reached ();
#endif
    return pid;
}
#endif
```

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/1da2d9803f4e8816a41a2d1aba65ed9011791b83/mono/mini/mini-posix.c#L1040